# How to execute a python file using txt file as input (to parse data)

Tags: python, command-line

I tried looking inside stackoverflow and other sources, but could not find the solution.

I am trying to run/execute a Python script (that parses the data) using a text file as input.

How do I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have any prior programming knowledge?

Comment: Sorry I am very new to Python.

Comment: so do you have programming experience in other languages?

Comment: Yes, very minor in C# and VB.NET, but new to open Python.

Comment: Look up how to read from `stdin`.

Comment: So you have a working python script you just need to pass the path of the text file to the script when executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These basics can be found using google :)

- http://pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/
- http://www.python-course.eu/python3_execute_script.php

Since you are new to Python make sure that you read [Python For Beginners](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/)

Sample code `Read.py`:

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
print contents
```

To execute this program in Windows:

```
C:\Users\Username\Desktop>python Read.py sample.txt
```

Comment: I was using Linux and the solution was simply typing:                                                                                                              python xx.py  yy.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving the input in the desired format (line-wise) file, and then using it as an alternative to STDIN (standard input file) using the file subcommand with Python

```
python source.py file input.txt
```

Note: To use it with input or source files in any other directory, use complete file location instead of file names.